# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier doesn't maintain instance inside closure

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading the following code in the main controller. I have debugged to assure it is calling the WebPortalViewController with no issues.

**Parent Controller A.viewDidLoad()**

```
    let sponsorViewController:UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Child")   
    childViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()
    childViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The Issue is however that the viewDidLoad function relies on execution of an operation call

**Child Controller B.viewDidload()**

```
    let operation = GetActiveSubscriptionOperation()

    operation.getActiveSubscriptionCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (subscription, error) in

      switch (self, subscription, error) {
```

`self` is always null until the view Controller is loaded directly from the UITabController. How do I get the `getActiveSubscriptionCompletionBlock` to maintain `self` in the closure?

Comment: You haven't shown the full context of your code, but I assume that the `let sponsorViewController...` is inside some function. As soon as that function exits, the `let` variable does out of scope.  Since the closure is using `weak self`,  that isn't enough to keep the view controller around, so it is released. The instance of the view controller that is loaded by your tab controller is a different instance.

Comment: Unfortunately the closure is only allowing me to use weak or unowned because it is implementing a callback of ServerOperation callbackQueue.addOperationWithBlock

Comment: The weak isn't the problem. Ow you are trying to load the data is the problem. You should load the data in the `viewDidLoad` and just let the standard process take care of instantiating the view controller for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by standard process but I edited the answer to clarify that both blocks or code are contained within the viewDidLoad() methods of each class.

Comment: Your second view controller is loaded into a tab bar controller; this will be a different instance of controller B than the one you are creating (unnecessarily) in vc A `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I am trying to preload the webview at boot-time using the following example: https://coderwall.com/p/trjkcg/preloading-uiwebview-or-wkwebview-in-swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137711/discussion-between-paulw11-and-joseph-persie).

Answer (score 0):

`weak` is declared as an Optional, variable could be nil if not reachable. So it is normal getting nil until viewcontroller loaded.

For me viewDidLoad should not rely on a execution of function it is in lifecycle of viewcontroller.

Comment: The viewController does load though because I can see debug output in that viewDidload function. I agree, unfortunately I am stuck with this code. would it not be smart to move the operation to the parent controller and then somehow inject and dependecies into the viewController?

Comment: I think so I would be a great move!